# App Engine Datastore Pricing: Reads with Large Offsets

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

For my Google App Engine app, I often need to use large offsets (2000 or more) into the datastore. I know this is not best practice, but I'd like to know the most cost effective way to do these.

Can I use the `keys_only` feature to make this cost effective?

For example, if I make a `keys_only` query with an offset of 2000 and limit of 10, then pull the 10 items by their key, I should only be charged 11 datastore reads, correct? If I didn't use `keys_only`, I'd be charged for 2011 reads, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `keys_only` queries would help, your calculation seems correct. From [Pricing and Quota](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing):

> ```
> Small Operations Unlimited Free
> ```
>
> Small operations include calls to allocate Cloud Datastore IDs or
>   keys-only queries.

But in general you might want to switch to using [Cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/query-cursors) instead of offsets, for more reasons than just costs. From [Offsets versus cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/query-cursors#offsets_versus_cursors):

> Although Cloud Datastore supports integer offsets, you should avoid
>   using them. Instead, use cursors. Using an offset only avoids
>   returning the skipped entities to your application, but these entities
>   are still retrieved internally. The skipped entities do affect the
>   latency of the query, and your application is billed for the read
>   operations required to retrieve them. Using cursors instead of offsets
>   lets you avoid all these costs.

Comment: I'm not sure if this sentence is true when `keys_only=True`: "The skipped entities do affect the latency of the query, and your application is billed for the read operations required to retrieve them."

Comment: I can confirm that `keys_only=True` does lower the cost. I just switched many of my queries over to that, and my bill lowered significantly.